# Pagefeed does not work correctly after first print

Tags: c#, printing

Using instructions, I found on stackoverflow I can print across multiple pages. But if I print the document multiple times without leaving the app, the pages are combined.

Result: First time 4 separate pages after 4 prints only 1 single page.

Here is my code (the form just has a single button). I think I need to reset something somewhere but can't figure it out. Appreciate your help!

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PrintIt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int N, Y, PageNr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Print";
            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printit);

            // Initialize the dialog's PrinterSettings property to hold user
            // defined printer settings.
            pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings =
                new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();

            //Show the dialog storing the result.
            DialogResult result = pageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.PaperSize;
                printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Landscape;

                string message = "Would you like to view the print preview first?";
                string caption = "Print Preview";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;

                Y = 0;
                N = 0;
                PageNr = 1;

                result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons); // Displays the MessageBox.
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
                     ((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1]).Items[0]).Enabled = false;//disable the direct print from printpreview.as when we click that Print button PrintPage event fires again.
                    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
                }


                if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    printDocument1.Print();
                }
                
            }
        }

        private void printit(System.Object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Font LFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
            float fontHeight = LFont.GetHeight();
            int startY = 40;
            int pageHeight = printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height;

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Page:" + PageNr, LFont, Brushes.Black, PageNr * 100, 10);
            for (int i = Y; i < 200; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Line: " + i, LFont, Brushes.Black, PageNr * 100, startY + N);
                N += (int)fontHeight;

                if (startY + N >= pageHeight - 100)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    N = 0;
                    Y = i;
                    PageNr += 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. At first, I added the necessary print objects from the toolbox onto the form design.  While this works it does not handle multiple pages correctly.

I now removed those objects from the form design and added them in code when the button is pressed:

```
PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
PageSetupDialog pageSetupDialog1 = new PageSetupDialog();
PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
```

Works like a charm!